# guardar campo id en distintas tablas de SQL desde ventana Windows forms C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, datagridview

Estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto mediante C#, utilizando Winforms y SQL para la base de datos. Bueno el asunto es que estoy bloqueado y no se como resolver la siguiente situación por eso la expongo esperando poder obtener alguna ayuda y orientaciones al respecto.

Tengo 2 tablas donde se asientan los datos de las compras (una para la cabecera que guarda los campos de varios textbox y la otra tabla para el detalle que guarda los datos que se van insertando al datagridview). Me funciona de forma correcta si le obligo al usuario a colocar el campo NRO_REG que vendría a ser el id de ambas tablas pero lo que *quiero es que el usuario no escriba ese nro_REG sino que el mismo sistema sea el encargado de generar ese id* y ese es mi problema.
Las tablas son:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COMPRAS](
[NRO_REG] [float] PRIMARY KEY,
[NRO_FACTURA] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
[FECHA_FACTURA] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[TIPO_DOCUMENTO] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[TIMBRADO] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
[FECHA_FIN_TIMBRADO] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[COD_PROV] [int] NOT NULL,
[IMPORTE_GRAVADO_5] [decimal](25, 5) NULL,
[IMPORTE_GRAVADO_10] [decimal](25, 5) NULL,
[IMPORTE_EXENTO] [decimal](25, 5) NULL,
[IMPORTE_IMPUESTO_5] [decimal](25, 5) NULL,
[IMPORTE_IMPUESTO_10] [decimal](25, 5) NULL,
[IMPORTE_TOTAL] [decimal](25, 5) NULL,
[OBSERVACION] [varchar](100) NULL
CONSTRAINT TIPO_DOCUMENTO_COMPRA FOREIGN KEY (TIPO_DOCUMENTO) REFERENCES  COMPRAS_TIPO_DOCUMENTOS(TIPO_DOCUMENTO),
CONSTRAINT COD_PROV FOREIGN KEY (COD_PROV) REFERENCES PROVEEDORES(COD_PROV)
)

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COMPRAS_DET](
[NRO_REG] [float] NOT NULL,
[CODIGO] [int] NOT NULL,
[UNIDADES] [decimal](12, 3) NOT NULL,
[PRECIO_BRUTO] [decimal](25, 5) NOT NULL,
[PRECIO_NETO] [decimal](25, 5) NOT NULL,
[IMPUESTO] [int] NOT NULL,
[SUBTOTAL] [decimal](25, 5) NOT NULL,
[PRIMARIO] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
CONSTRAINT NRO_REG_COMPRA FOREIGN KEY (NRO_REG) REFERENCES COMPRAS(NRO_REG),
CONSTRAINT CODIGO_COMPRA FOREIGN KEY (CODIGO) REFERENCES PRODUCTOS(CODIGO)
)

GO
```

y en el boton para insertar los datos mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
private void Crear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string insertar = "INSERT INTO COMPRAS (NRO_REG,COD_PROV,TIPO_DOCUMENTO,NRO_FACTURA,FECHA_FACTURA,TIMBRADO,FECHA_FIN_TIMBRADO,IMPORTE_TOTAL,IMPORTE_EXENTO,IMPORTE_GRAVADO_5,IMPORTE_GRAVADO_10,IMPORTE_IMPUESTO_5,IMPORTE_IMPUESTO_10,OBSERVACION) Values (@NRO_REG,@COD_PROV,@TIPO_DOCUMENTO,@NRO_FACTURA,@FECHA_FACTURA,@TIMBRADO,@FECHA_FIN_TIMBRADO,@IMPORTE_TOTAL,@IMPORTE_EXENTO,@IMPORTE_GRAVADO_5,@IMPORTE_GRAVADO_10,@IMPORTE_IMPUESTO_5,@IMPORTE_IMPUESTO_10,@OBSERVACION)";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertar, con);
            
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NRO_REG", SqlDbType.Float).Value = altoTextBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@COD_PROV", SqlDbType.Int, 50).Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TIPO_DOCUMENTO", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = comboBox2.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NRO_FACTURA", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = altoTextBox6.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FECHA_FACTURA", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = maskedTextBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TIMBRADO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = altoTextBox4.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FECHA_FIN_TIMBRADO", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = maskedTextBox2.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMPORTE_TOTAL", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textBox6.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMPORTE_EXENTO", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMPORTE_GRAVADO_5", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textBox2.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMPORTE_GRAVADO_10", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textBox3.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMPORTE_IMPUESTO_5", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textBox5.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMPORTE_IMPUESTO_10", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textBox4.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OBSERVACION", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = altoTextBox2.Text;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            string insertar2 = "INSERT INTO COMPRAS_DET (NRO_REG,CODIGO,UNIDADES,PRECIO_BRUTO,PRECIO_NETO,IMPUESTO,SUBTOTAL) values (@NRO_REG2,@CODIGO,@UNIDADES,@PRECIO_BRUTO,@PRECIO_NETO,@IMPUESTO,@SUBTOTAL)";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertar2, con);

            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    cmd2.Parameters.Clear(); 
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@NRO_REG2", SqlDbType.Float).Value = altoTextBox1.Text;
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@CODIGO", SqlDbType.Int, 50).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@UNIDADES", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@PRECIO_BRUTO", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[5].Value);
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@PRECIO_NETO", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[6].Value);
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@IMPUESTO", SqlDbType.Int, 50).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Value);
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@SUBTOTAL", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[7].Value);
                    
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                
            }
            
            
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Compra cargada correctamente.");
        }
```

Como se ve el dato NRO_REG lo guarda del dato que el usuario escriba en **altotextobox1**.Ya probé de colocar la propiedad IDENTITY (1,1) en campo NRO_REG de tabla COMPRAS para que genere automaticamente el campo NRO_REG y sacarlo de ambos insert pero entonces en la tabla COMPRAS_DET nose como seguir, y ahí ya no me graba más el detalle (sería el segundo insert).

Les agradezco de antemano a los que se hagan un tiempo y traten de ayudarme a resolverlo.

Comment: Ademas de lo que te marque en la duplicada, todo debe estar envuelto en una trasaccion

Comment: Bueno comento que he encontrado solución y paso a comentarla por si a alguien más le sirva. Probé el scope identity () pero no me funcionó, seguía sin asentarme los datos en la segunda tabla. Pero me dio la idea de modificar para que en la misma query sea la que seleccione el id: "INSERT INTO COMPRAS_DET (NRO_REG,CODIGO,...........,SUBTOTAL) values ((select MAX(NRO_REG) as NRO_REG from COMPRAS),@CODIGO,...........,@SUBTOTAL)";